# There were custom validation error(s) encountered [Mailing Longitude]"

Tags: validation

There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Required fields are missing: [Mailing Longitude]".

this just started to happen when saving a (Specific) contact record (Not all and have not found another that it happens on yet).

Cloning the contact record allows the cloned contact to be saved and edited.

No validation rules exist on the Contact, nor are there any trigger on contact. No debug logs are created so nothing to trace.

Has anyone seen this happen before